# How can Android code interface with Javascript code in a WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I know you can take an instance of a webview and call addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(context), "nameofinterface") to allow javascript to send data to Android Java code. But how do I go the other way? I want to tell javascript to play a video at a specific point in time when I hit the back button on my android device. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:function()");
```

You can put it here:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, it'd be nice if Javascript was mentioned in the android documentation with this method.

Comment: Afaik, this is also how you do it in most browser scripting languages. A relevant mention in the docs would be nice though